# IDE suggestion - auto closes tags on </

Tags: html, ide, autocomplete, tags

I've been using **Dreamweaver CS3** for far to long, and now that most of my coding is PHP (often using CodeIgniter), I really need to find a new IDE.

I've tried **PHPDesigner** and **Aptana Studio 3**, and was happy with both until I started coding in HTML and saw how they auto-close their tags as soon as one is opened, placing the cursor between them. After a lot of searching around the web, this seems to be the norm, but I've become very used to Dreamweavers style of auto-closing the most recent opened tag when I type `</` and place my cursor at the end of the generated closing tag.

Are there any IDEs out there that auto-close their tags on `</` or am I asking too much?

Comment: I've posted on the aptana studio support page, and in the next release (3.0.3) they'll be fixing a bug that will allow you to hit </+Enter to close tags. I've suggested adding an option to automatically insert the "best" closing tag when typing </ (without Enter), so we'll see

Comment: Quick update in case someone comes across this looking for the same - I've settled on Aptana Studio 3, and have had a feature request made to do something like what I want. Guess I can only hope they include it in a future version

Answer (score 1):

By default, Netbeans 7 provides the behavior you observed in PHPDesigner and Aptana Studio 2. However, the behavior can be changed via Preferences -> Code Completion -> HTML to the auto-close style that you prefer.

Look specifically for the "Completion Offers End Tags After Less Than (<) Character" option.

Comment: Thanks George, I had Netbeans on my list of IDEs to try out, but I just tried accessing their site, and they seem to be doing server maintenance. I'll let you know how it goes once I can get on the site and grab a copy.

Comment: @steve: FWIW, there is a list of mirrors (authenticity unknown) here: http://netbeans.dzone.com/announcements/netbeans-downloads-available-m

Comment: Any help finding Preferences -> Code Completion -> HTML in 8.0.2? I can't even find Preferences.

Comment: In netbeans 8 it would be, `Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion`, then on the Language dropdown set `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

I used Espresso before, it only works on Mac but it is quite good. It has auto close but I think Dreamweaver has it too.